# How do I get marshal size of a specific property from a type in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

In .NET Core there is only a generic method `Marshal.SizeOf<T>()` available (`Marshal.SizeOf(Type t)` is deprecated). But I would like to enumerate all properties of a class and get marshal size of them. How do I do?

This is my code: (not actually mine but the code I'm trying to port to .NET Core)

from https://github.com/kapetan/dns/blob/master/DNS/Protocol/Marshalling/Struct.cs with modifications

```
private static byte[] ConvertEndian<T>(byte[] data)
{
    var fields = typeof(T).GetRuntimeFields().Where(f => f.IsStatic == false);
    EndianAttribute endian = typeof(T).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<EndianAttribute>();

    foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
    {
        if (endian == null && field.GetCustomAttribute<EndianAttribute>(false) == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int offset = Marshal.OffsetOf<T>(field.Name).ToInt32();

        // *** This is deprecated ***
        // int length = Marshal.SizeOf(field.FieldType);

        // *** This doesn't work at all ***
        int length = field.FieldType.GetTypeInfo().StructLayoutAttribute.Size;

        endian = endian ?? field.GetCustomAttribute<EndianAttribute>(false);

        if (endian.Endianness == Endianness.Big && BitConverter.IsLittleEndian ||
                endian.Endianness == Endianness.Little && !BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(data, offset, length);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8043

Comment: You should not be writing code like this, it is fundamentally incompatible with ahead-of-time compilation (aka .NET Native).  Which is quite crucial in .NETCore, the hundreds of little assemblies completely kill cold-start times dead.  It is not like you can't do this another way, BinaryReader also lets you read network packets.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to decide what generic type should be used in runtime. There is really a way to do it: the **dynamic** type.
The [C# Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx#)  says,

> The dynamic type enables the operations in which it occurs to bypass compile-time type checking. Instead, these operations are resolved at run time.

So you can define a method:

```
static int GetLength<T>(T obj)
{
    return Marshal.SizeOf<T>();
}
```

And then create an instance of type `T` as dynamic by reflection:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType.GetTypeInfo());
int length = GetLength(obj);
```

The runtime will choose a suitable type parameter T for the method.

This solution has a limitation that you can't create an instance of a type which hasn't default constructor. You may define a wrapper class `Wrapper<T>` with no real field, and create it as runtime in order to ensure the constructor works. But I have no idea whether it works.